# compare two json files and match entries with the same value

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, bigdata

I need compare two json files on keys: a,b,c,d,e

If all keys is match for entry between json file 1 and json file 2
so i should find delta betwen platform_time for this entry.
And then delete this entries from json file 1 and json file 2.
(both json files have 10000000000 entries ):

So here we should match :

```
1) one[0] and [two][1] 
2) one[1] and [two][]
```

Data json one and json two:
first file -

```
"one": [
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:00.000",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "1",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:00.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "2",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 87
    },      
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:10.001",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "6",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    },...]
```

second file -

```
"two": [
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "2",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 87
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:10.001",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "1",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "200",
        "d" : "2021-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 81
    },...
    ]
```

I start doing something like this, but iteration for all elements takes too much time.

Could you please help me optimize my code ?

```
    import datetime
    import json
    import numpy as np
    import random``
    lst_in_seconds = []
    
    f = open('one_all.json')
    one = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    
    f1 = open('two_all.json')
    two = json.load(f1)
    f1.close()
    
    counter_one_better = 0
    counter_two_better = 0
    counter_the_same = 0

for k in range(10000000000):
   for i in range(10000000000):
    if one['one'][k]['b'] == two['two'][i]['b'] and one['one'][k]['e'] == two['two'][i]['e'] 
    and one['one'][k]['amount'] == two['two'][i]['amount'] 
    and one['one'][k]['d'] == two['two'][i]['d'] 
    and one['one'][k]['c'] == two['two'][i]['c']:
            if (one['one'][k]['a']) < (two['two'][i]['a']):
                # one better than two
                delt_one = datetime.datetime.strptime((one['one'][k]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                delt_two = datetime.datetime.strptime((two['two'][i]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                delta = delt_two - delt_one
                diff_in_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
                lst_in_seconds.append(diff_in_seconds)
                counter_one_better += 1
                two['two'][i]['b'] = random.randint(0,100000)
                break

                elif (one['one'][k]['a']) == (two['two'][i]['a']):
                    # same
                    delt_one = datetime.datetime.strptime((one['one'][k]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                    delt_two = datetime.datetime.strptime((two['two'][i]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                    delta = delt_two - delt_one
                    diff_in_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
                    lst_in_seconds.append(diff_in_seconds)
                    counter_the_same += 1
                    two['two'][i]['b'] = random.randint(0,100000)
                    break

                elif (one['one'][k]['a']) > (two['two'][i]['a']):
                    delt_one = datetime.datetime.strptime((one['one'][k]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                    delt_two = datetime.datetime.strptime((two['two'][i]['a']), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                    delta = delt_one - delt_two
                    diff_in_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
                    diff_in_seconds_to_str = float(('-' + str(diff_in_seconds)))
                    lst_in_seconds.append(diff_in_seconds_to_str)
                    counter_two_better += 1
                    two['two'][i]['b'] = random.randint(0,100000)
                    break

    #print('counter_the_same',counter_the_same,'count')
    #print('counter_one_better',counter_one_better,'count')
    #print('counter_two_better',counter_two_better,'count','\n')
    print('one better than two in ', round((counter_one_better / (counter_two_better+counter_one_better+counter_the_same))*100,4),'% case')
    print('the same ', round((counter_the_same / (counter_two_better+counter_one_better+counter_the_same))*100,4),'% case')
    print('two better than one in ', round((counter_two_better / (counter_two_better+counter_one_better+counter_the_same))*100,4),'% case','\n')
```

Comment: Instead of using a nested loop (O(n²)) try a single loop with a next() function with a generator expression to find a match, if there is one. match = next(d for d in json2 if d['a'] == json1[a] and d['b'] == json1[b].. etc). I also don't like explicitly setting the range of the loop. Why not just len(json1)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time taken to compare the files by pre-processing the two files to dictionaries with keys of the values to be compared. Then for each entry in `one`, you can look up the entries in `two` which have the same `b`,`c`,`d`, and `e` values and compare the times. Note that you can make your code a lot more "DRY" by noting that the only difference in the three branches of the `if` is which counter is updated.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
import random

one = { "one": [
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:00.000",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "1",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:00.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "2",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 87
    },      
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:10.001",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "6",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    }
] }

two = { "two": [
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "2",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 87
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:10.001",
        "b" : "apple",
        "c" : "1",
        "d" : "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 88
    },
    {
        "a" : "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000",
        "b" : "orange",
        "c" : "200",
        "d" : "2021-09-11 23:59:59.997",
        "e" : 81
    }
] }

compare_keys = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
value_key = 'a'
set_key = 'b'

ones = defaultdict(list)
for o in one['one']:
    ones[tuple(o[k] for k in compare_keys)].append(o[value_key])

twos = defaultdict(list)
for t in two['two']:
    twos[tuple(t[k] for k in compare_keys)].append({ k : t[k] for k in [value_key, set_key] })

counter_one_better = 0
counter_two_better = 0
counter_the_same = 0
lst_in_seconds = []

for k, o in ones.items():
    t = twos.get(k)
    if t is None:
        continue
    for o1 in o:
        for i, t2 in enumerate(t):
            delt_one = datetime.datetime.strptime(o1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            delt_two = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2[value_key], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            delta = delt_two - delt_one
            diff_in_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
            lst_in_seconds.append(diff_in_seconds)
            counter_one_better += diff_in_seconds < 0
            counter_the_same += diff_in_seconds == 0
            counter_two_better += diff_in_seconds > 0
            t[i][set_key] = random.randint(0,100000)

print(counter_one_better, counter_the_same, counter_two_better)
print(lst_in_seconds)

# reconstruct the two dict
new_two = { 'two' : [ dict([*zip(compare_keys, k), *v.items()]) for k in twos for v in twos[k] ] }
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
# counter_one_better, counter_the_same, counter_two_better
0 0 2
# lst_in_seconds
[10.001, 30.0]
# new_two
{
    "two": [
        {
            "b": 4459,
            "c": "2",
            "d": "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
            "e": 87,
            "a": "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000"
        },
        {
            "b": 93855,
            "c": "1",
            "d": "2022-09-11 23:59:59.997",
            "e": 88,
            "a": "2022-09-12 00:00:10.001"
        },
        {
            "b": "orange",
            "c": "200",
            "d": "2021-09-11 23:59:59.997",
            "e": 81,
            "a": "2022-09-12 00:00:30.000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?